# Error when changing the color of android apps background

Tags: android, xml, colors, background, gradient

When I use normal color as a background of my apps, the apk succesfully builds and the apps running perfectly on my device.

The problem is when I change the background to a gradient color background, the apk succesfully builds but the app crashes on my device.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/renunganbutton"
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_weight="3" 
             android:background="#212326" 
             android:src="@drawable/renungan"/>
```

Comment: Could you post how you use the gradient background in you xml-s?

Comment: Share your LogCat when your app get crashed .

Comment: @AhlemJarrar the apk succesfully build but when i try to run the apps on my device the apps got crash

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml file for example `gradient.xml` in drawable folder and then try to write this code:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:centerColor="#5b5b5b"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:angle="0" />
```

Possible angles are:

> 0, 90, 180, 270

and then set the background of your element in MainActivity.xml like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient.xml"
```

Comment: my code same like you, and when i build the apk. the apk succesfuly build.
but when i open the apps on my device the apps got crashes